# Email users migration from Redhat's Sendmail to Centos Postfix/Dovecot

Tags: postfix, sendmail, migration, dovecot

I am using sendmail in Redhat linux where mail stored in /var/spool/mail. I migrated all the email users related files to Centos where i have configured postfix/dovecot with the help of the following site ; 
http://www.krizna.com/centos/setup-mail-server-in-centos-6/

When i m creating new user, the mail system is working fine. But for the migrated user it is not working.
I gave the configuration:
In  `/etc/postfix/main.cf`      --> `home_mailbox = mail/`
And under /`etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf` --> `mail_location = maildir:~/mail` and
                                  `pop3_uidl_format = %08Xu%08Xv`

For migrated users there is no directory named mail under /home/user.
what is the easiest way to resolve the problem. Giving the following error:

> postfix/local[3522]: warning: maildir access problem for UID/GID=500/500: create maildir file /home/rony/mail/tmp/1473118580.P3522.mail.it.ivoryajmiree.com: Permission denied
>   Sep  6 05:36:20 mail postfix/qmgr[2283]: 1F7A6348034E: from=<>, size=2775, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>   Sep  6 05:36:20 mail postfix/bounce[3523]: E0B52348034C: sender non-delivery notification: 1F7A6348034E
>   Sep  6 05:36:20 mail postfix/qmgr[2283]: E0B52348034C: removed
>   Sep  6 05:36:20 mail postfix/local[3522]: warning: maildir access problem for UID/GID=500/500: create maildir file  /home/rony/mail/tmp/1473118580.P3522.mail.it.ivoryajmiree.com: Permission denied
>   Sep  6 05:36:20 mail postfix/local[3522]: warning: perhaps you need to create the maildirs in advance

Comment: The easiest way to solve your problem is to actually read the error message you copied into your question ***"you need to create the maildirs"*** i.e. create the `cur/ new/ tmp/` subdirectories required for the Maildir message store in  `~mail/`

Comment: I have 400+ users. Actually need to know how could i create essential directories with appropriate permission for all users in easiest way.

Comment: The easiest way would have been to consider that beforehand and add the necessary directories to the `/etc/skel` home directory template, then they would have been added when you created your users. Since that is probably water under the bridge, depending on your homedir ownerships a trivial for-loop: `cd /home;  for USER in * ; do echo "mkdir -p /home/$USER/maildir/{cur,new,tmp} ; chown -R $USER:GID /home/$USER/maildir/ ; chmod 0700 /home/$USER/maildir/" ; done`

Comment: @HBruijn, thanks for your greatest effort. When i give the command "mkdir -p /home/$USER/maildir/{cur,new,tmp}" it only applies on root user. but instead of $USER when i give a user name like "rony" it applies for that user. But for that specific user “rony”, the command : chown -R rony:GID /home/rony/maildir/ ; is not working, giving the message " chown: invalid group: 'rony:GID' ".

Comment: please note that all of my migrated users are member of "mail" group the ID of mail group is 12. In /etc/passwd file information for migrated user “rony” is ; rony:x:501:12:Shamsul Alam:/home/rony:/bin/false; and information for newly created user “ bobby:x:501:501::/home/bobby:/sbin/nologin ”. how could I declare all the folders under /home through one command??